# Why aren't chars on the stack one apart?

Tags: c++, stack

When I run:

```
void samp(int a = 0, int b = 2,unsigned char c = 1, unsigned char d = 2 )
{
    std::cout  << reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&b)- reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&a) << "," << reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&c) - reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&a) << "," << reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&d) - reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(&a) << std::endl;
}
```

I get 4,8,12. I would have expected 4,5,6, as `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1, and I don't think there are padding issues. Is this implementation-defined? What am I missing?

Comment: ***Is this implementation-defined?*** Yes.

Comment: Don't do pointer arithmetic on unrelated objects.  It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah, this was mostly curiosity on why it was behaving that way. If it's implementation defined you can't expect anything.

Comment: **Computational efficiency** trumps **storage efficiency** there, obviously.

Comment: As an aside, implementation-defined would mean it is consistent, documented, and the standard probably gave a limited number of alternatives to choose from. It's not.

Comment: Accessing an aligned variable is often faster than accessing an unaligned one. On some systems unaligned loads/stores are not even possible. (For various values of alignment).

Comment: Though implementation-defined, `char` parameters are usually pushed on the call stack as `int` values to help maintain stack alignment.

Comment: To underscore what Deduplicator said, being undefined behavior is something the optimizer can take into account.  That means that the optimizer can do things that may make no sense from a behavior standpoint, when the behavior is dependent on undefined behavior.  That can be important even when `-O0` optimizations are turned off.

Comment: This is not even implementation defined, it is unspecified. a,b,c, and d can either be where the function call placed them and then it is up to the ABI. They can also be local copies inside the function and then the compiler is free to place them more or less as it wishes.